# HTML page to windows gadget

Tags: html, windows-desktop-gadgets

I created a basic HTML5 page with some canvas drawing and third party meter gauge.
The page works well in browser.
I created a Windows 7 gadget out of it like given here: http://blog.brandoncopley.com/?p=69
But the gadget shows only white color.
It seems like no javascript s getting executed or canvas drawing is done.

I have tried following option to resolve the issue: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/140358-gadgets-not-displaying-correctly-windows-7-fix.html

The Reset_gadgets.bat file also did not help.
All other gadgets are working good.

The gadget.xml looks like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<gadget> 
<name>simple</name> 
<version>1.0.0.0</version> 
<author name="MaxRecursion"> 
<info url="maxrecursion.wordpress.com" /> 
<logo src="logo.png"/> 
</author> 
<copyright>&#169; MaxRecursion.</copyright> 
<description>This is a simple gadget.</description> 
<hosts> 
<host name="sidebar"> 
<base type="HTML" apiVersion="1.0.0" src="index.html" /> 
<permissions>Full</permissions> 
<platform minPlatformVersion="1.0" /> 
</host> 
</hosts> 
</gadget>
```

I am new with the Windows 7 gadgets, what can be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Gadgets run on IE7, so they don't support canvas. Excanvas (http://excanvas.sourceforge.net/) seems to work fine, and it's very easy to use. Just download the .js, put it in a folder with your gadget, and call it from the html before you use anything canvas related. That's it, it works its magic by itself, and the canvas tag will work the way it's supposed to.

Comment: It seems that transparency can be a problem, tho. Usually solved by using <g:image> instead of <img>, but I'm not sure how to do it with canvas..